# Field Display styling, different font sizes for the text inside

Tags: css, extjs

I am building a web application using ExtJS4 and I have a Field Display where I show the full name of the user selected.

I am fetching the username as such:

```
var firstName = record.get('FIRST_NAME');
var middleName = record.get('MIDDLE_NAME');
var lastName = record.get('LAST_NAME');

var name = firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;
```

My `displayfield` is inside a `panel` and is defined as such:

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    x: 175,
    y: 355,
    itemId: 'userName',
    maxWidth: 300,
    minWidth: 300,
    width: 300,
    defaultAlign: 'center',
    hideLabel: true,
    labelWidth: 60,
    fieldStyle: 'font-size: 16px; color: #ffff00; text-align: center; text-style: bold;'

}
```

and I am setting my `displayfield` as such:

```
Ext.getCmp('borrowerIconPanel').down('#borrowerFormPanel').down('#userName').setRawValue(name);
```

However, that only displays the `name` in the `fieldStyle` that I defined to be:

```
font-size: 16px; color: #ffff00; text-align: center; text-style: bold;
```

What I want to happen is that the `lastName` has a different font size than `firstName` and `middleName`. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I'm not too savvy with changing styles in ExtJS.

Comment: No it's not, my `fieldDisplay` is directly under a panel.

Comment: panel does not have a fieldDisplay property, can you post the actual code for the #userName

Comment: I can see only one display field, so I don't understand what you meant with "that only displays the name in the fieldStyle that I defined to be". What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Three fields with different styles or one field with a different style for each part of the name?

Comment: One field with a  different style for each part of the name.

Comment: updated my answer with working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add some formatting in the output, Below I have wrapped the response in a `span` element with a CSS class that defines the required styles. I have used an inline style block in the HTML for the example, you should add this to your application's stylesheet.

```
<style>
.bold-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: blue;
}
</style>

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'vbox',
            title: 'Final Score',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                id: 'userName',
                fieldLabel: "Test",
                value: 'This is a test',
                flex: 1,
                fieldStyle: 'font-size: 16px; color: #000; text-align: center; text-style: bold;'
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                id: 'userName2',
                fieldLabel: "Test",
                flex: 1,
                value: 'This is a test'
            }],
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function() {
                    var firstName = "John";
                    var middleName = "Arthur";
                    var lastName = "Smith";

                    var name = firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;

                    Ext.getCmp('userName').setRawValue(name);

                    var name = firstName + " " + middleName + " <span class='bold-text'>" + lastName +"</span>";

                    Ext.getCmp('userName2').setRawValue(name);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h0k)

Comment: What if I want lastname to have a different style than firstname and secondname? I tried this and it doesn't work. `var name = "<span class='lastname-text'>" + lastName + "</span>" + 
                ", <span class = 'firstname-text>" + firstName + " " + middleName + "</span>";`

Comment: nevermind, I was missing a `'` after the `firstname-text`. thanks!